# What exactly does the persistence API do and what are the advantages of using it?

Tags: java, api, persistence

Is the Persistence API similar to JDBC?  In other words, is its purpose for connecting to the database?  Also, does it use SQL?  And what advantage would someone using persistence have over using jdbc?  Why not just use jdbc? I've looked at a number of websites about persistence but yet am still a little confused about exactly what it is and why using it would provide the programmer an advantage.

Comment: What do you mean by persistence API? ORM?

Comment: I am referring to persistence API as discussed in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/persistence-jsp-136066.html

Comment: this is not a real question, too broad and opinion based, in short **off topic**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answers:

The API you referenced is typically called "JPA" - that'll be the most useful term to search for when you have questions.

Yes, JPA is a replacement for/complement to JDBC.  Typically you'll do everything using JPA calls, but you can get a JDBC Connection from most JPA implementations and use that if you need to.

Yes, it uses SQL under the covers - it's a client-layer abstraction around the raw SQL calls.

The advantage is that it allows you to use an object-style interface when interacting with the database, and skip long, error-prone code related to mapping DB result columns to fields in your objects.

```
MyObject obj = em.find(someKey, ...);
obj.getFoo();
obj.getBar();
```

is a lot more maintainable than

```
String query = "select foo, bar, baz, wibble, whomp from myObject_table where pk_field = someKey";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
rs.next();
rs.get("foo");
rs.get("bar");
```

Comment: Your answer really helped me to understand.  Thank you for taking the time.